# Dataview custom filter on time component of datetime column

Tags: c#, wpf, dataview, datagridviewcolumn

I have datagrid view with 2 columns.

```
| ID | DateCol             |
| 5  | 2021-02-12 03:05:01 |
| 4  | 2021-02-15 02:05:01 |
| 3  | 2021-02-15 05:05:01 |
| 2  | 2021-02-13 05:05:01 |
| 1  | 2021-02-12 05:05:01 |
```

On applying custom filter to collection view:

```
BindingListCollectionView collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ItemsSource);
collectionview.CustomFilter = $"CONVERT(DateCol, 'System.String') >= #05:00:00#";
```

I get only one result:

```
   | 3  | 2021-02-15 05:05:01 |
```

Seems like it's taking DateTime of today that is 15th Feb. How to filter just based on time?

Expected output is all 3 items which has time of day component greater than 0500.

```
    | 3  | 2021-02-15 05:05:01 |
    | 2  | 2021-02-13 05:05:01 |
    | 1  | 2021-02-12 05:05:01 |
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
this.defaultView.Filter =
            w =>
            {
                var dateTimeColumn = w as DataTimeColumn;
                return dateTimeColumn?.DateTimeCol.Hour > 5;
            };

        this.defaultView.Refresh();
```

you can achieve the filtering with the above piece of code when you are using **ICollectionView** as **ItemsSource** for your DataGrid.

Comment: while using Filter on BindingListCollectionView, I am getting 'Specified method is not supported', also can't find DateTimeColumn as well .. what's it's namespace

Comment: @ThomasBecker to not make any confusion, here DataTimeColumn is the class name which is created by me and it has two properties one is Id with int type and another one is DateTimeCol which is of DateTime type

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
BindingListCollectionView collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ItemsSource) as BindingListCollectionView;
collectionView.CustomFilter = $"SUBSTRING(CONVERT(DateCol, 'System.String'), 11, 8) >= #05:00:00#";
```